# cannot gate index of arrival gate of new message in omnet++ 5.6.1

Tags: c++, runtime-error, simulation, omnet++

I am following the tictoc tutorial and I want to change the code of tictoc12 so that I'll get the index of the gate from which we received the message so that the message will not send out from the same gate. This is my handleMesssage() function:

```
void Txc12::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
if (getIndex() == 3) {
    // Message arrived.
    EV << "Message " << msg << " arrived.\n";
    delete msg;
}
else {
    int arrivalGate = msg->getArrivalGate()->getIndex();
    EV << "arrival gate: " << arrivalGate << "\n";
    // We need to forward the message.
    forwardMessage(msg);
}
}
```

and this is the error that i receive:

> Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819
> Working directory: D:/omnetpp-5.6.1/samples/tictoc
> Command line: tictoc.exe -m -u Qtenv omnetpp.ini

> Environment variables:
> PATH=;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;;D:/omnetpp-5.6.1/ide/jre/bin/server;D:/omnetpp-5.6.1/ide/jre/bin;D:/omnetpp-5.6.1/ide/jre/lib/amd64;.;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;D:\omnetpp-5.6.1;
> OMNETPP_ROOT=D:/omnetpp-5.6.1/
> OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=D:\omnetpp-5.6.1\images

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You will probably need to use a debugger to figure out where and why you get an access violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of exit code `-1073741819` is equal to `0xC0000005` - an access violation. However, `handleMessage()` presented by you cannot be source of that error.
I strongly suggest using debugger to find the lines that cause that error. To do this:

1. Compile your project in debug mode.
2. In your `omnetpp.ini` set:

   ```
   debug-on-errors = true
   ```
3. Start your simulation in debug  (i.e. `Run` | `Debug`)

The execution of the simulation will stop just before the line that causes an exception.

Reference: [TicToc Tutorial - 2.3 Debugging](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/#23-debugging)

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice but it is doing it to the self messages too and because they do not arrive from a gate then it can't return its' index. so i just check if the message is self or not before getting the index